# Problem creating N*N*N list in Python

Tags: python, list, mutable

I'm trying to create a 3-dimensional N*N*N list in Python, like such:

```
n=3
l = [[[0,]*n]*n]*n
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to properly "clone" the list, as I thought it would:

```
>>> l
[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
>>> l[0][0][0]=1
>>> l
[[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you expect to do a lot of matrixy operations you can get into `numpy`, but I like using dicts indexed by tuples as multidimensional arrays: `from collections import defaultdict; d = defaultdict(int); d[0,0,0] = 1` - it might be a good fit for your 3D tic-tac-toe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `* n` does a shallow copy of the list. A solution is to use nested loops, or try the numpy library.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do numerical processing with 3-d matrix you are better of using numpy. It is quite easy:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.zeros((3,3,3), dtype=numpy.int)
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
>>> _[0,0,0]
0
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, it's building the 2nd and 3rd levels with references, not clones.  Try:

```
>>> n = 3

>>> l = [[[0]*n for _ in xrange(n)] for _ in xrange(n)]

>>> l[0][0][0] = 1

>>> l
[[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

Or if you want to type a bit less:

```
>>> l = [[[0]*n for _ in '.'*n] for _ in '.'*n]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not cloning the list.  It's inserting a reference to the same list over and over.  Try creating the list using a set of nested for loops.

Answer (score 2):

I have to second what leonardo-santagada suggested, with the addition that creating N dimensional arrays/lists is very unpythonic and you should reconsider how you're keeping your data and seeing if it doesn't belong better in a class or a list of dictionaries (or dictionaries of lists).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  I needed this to create a 3-dimensional tic-tac-toe board for an AI algorithm.  While it's true that numpy arrays might have sped up some operations, I figured this would be "good enough" for this small program.